# Problem with sticky footers

Tags: css

I'm trying to use [sticky footers](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) on my page but I'm having a problem where the footer appears below the window, even if there is no content.

[This page](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) says that this is caused by using `margin` on some of the elements, thus the footer is being "pushed" down by the accumulated values of the `margin`'s. The page suggests to replace `margin` with `padding`, but that breaks my design, since they aren't exactly the same thing.

What else can I do to "pull" the footer up?

Here's a link to show my problem: http://john2x.com/wordpress/?p=4

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing your page, your code, a jsfiddle, something...

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQcVH/). It's a Wordpress theme so it's messy and long, but the structure is basically the same as the one on [this page](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html), except I have divs with margins set in the main body, which the page says causes problems. This [demo page](http://john2x.com/wordpress/?p=4) shows the scrollbar/margin problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your div has padding maybe you should also sum the top and bottom paddings to the negative margin you're giving to it...

So for example if your div has 10px top and bottom margin, I think you should add 20px to its negative margins.

If there are elements with margin inside the footer that are pushing it down, maybe you should also add those margins to the negative margin of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is being caused by your #page-wrap min-height being set to 100%.

I think the easiest solution would be to move your footer div within the #page-wrap div, then it will fall within the bounds of the page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just tried it but now the footer is placed immediately below the content, and not at the bottom of the window (i.e. when the content is short).